# Trying to get signals to work in my QT. I need some advice and help

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

So I have in my main function:

```
string s = "\nWelcome to Rawr\n";
const QString output(s);
**emit output(output);       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Getting an error here**
```

I have set up a Signal in QT Desginer named: output(const QString &s)

My receiver for the signal is my "Form"... in my form.h i have:
The slot is called "changeOutput(const QString &s).

```
void Client::changeOutput(const QString &s)
{
    output_box.setText(s);
}
```

output_box is a QTextEdit box.

The error I am receiving is :
TCPClient.cpp:122: error: no match for call to ‘(const QString) (const QString&)’

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you declared a variable `output`, the name `output` refers to that variable in the local scope. The compiler doesn't know that in `output(output)` you want one `output` to refer to the variable and the other `output` to refer to the slot/method.

Use a different name for the local variable to avoid this collision.